# CloudFront - serve different object based on path pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving a static webpage using S3/Cloudfront.

I would like to serve different html based on path pattern:

```
example.com/dashboard -> app.html
example.com/profile -> app.html
example.com/homepage -> homepage.html
example.com/marketing -> homepage.html
```

I know that you can set a 'Default Root Object' in cloudfront, but I was wondering if you would serve different object based on path patterns.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't currently supported as written, but in an S3 bucket with web site hosting enabled, requesting `/homepage` or `/homepage/` will automatically render the object at `homepage/index.html` if you set the Index Document for the bucket as `index.html`.

Lambda@Edge should be able to do this it, once that service leaves prievew mode.